# how to use input function in multiple if statement

Tags: python

hi beginner here I'm learning if statement
this my code

```
print("Welcome to the dungeon.")
print("Your mission is to find the ursine sword.") 

level_1 = input("there is two doors infront of you type 'right' for the right door and 'left' for the left door.\n" )
level_1.lower()
if level_1 == "right" :
  print("this door is closed your level is too low to open it.\n")
if level_1 == "left" :
 level_2 = input("you found a two ladder one leads to upstairs type 'upstairs' and another leads to the basement type 'basement'.\n ")
level_2.lower()

if level_2 == "basement" :
   print("hisssssss ,  you got bitten by snake game over")
if level_2 == "upstairs" :
  level_3 =int(input("it seems like the final room thre is three swords infront of you two of them must be traps chose '1','2' or '3' "))
if level_3 == 1 :
  print("you released a powerful ghost you'r dead")
elif level_3 == 3 :
  print("you opened a portal to a cater you're dead")
elif level_3 == 2 :
  print("congratulations you found the ursine sword")
else :
  print("game over.")
```

I tried many other ways to use input but can't describe it  the issue is  level_2 is undefined
when i choose 'right'
but if i choose 'left' the code continue with no problem and i can choose 'upstairs' with no issue and continue with level_3 and can choose form 1,2,3 with no issue even though level_3 is inputted like level_2
or am I wrong?
#new code

```
print("Welcome to the dungeon.")
print("Your mission is to find the ursine sword.") 

print("Welcome to the dungeon.")
print("Your mission is to find the ursine sword.") 
level_1 = input("there is two doors infront of you type 'right' for the right door and 'left' for the left door.\n")
if level_1== "right":
  print("this door is closed your level is too low to open it.\n")
elif level_1== "left":
  level_2 =input("you found a two ladder one leads to upstairs type 'upstairs' and another leads to the basement type 'basement'.\n ").lower()
  if level_2== "basement":
    print("hisssssss ,  you got bitten by snake game over")
  elif level_2== "upstairs":
    level_3 = int(input("it seems like the final room thre is three swords infront of you two of them must be traps chose '1','2' or '3' "))
    if level_3 == 1 :
     print("you released a powerful ghost you'r dead")
    elif level_3 == 3 :
     print("you opened a portal to a cater you're dead")
    elif level_3 == 2 :
     print("congratulaitons you found the ursine sword")
else :
  print("game over.")
```

this the new code the indentation fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

Your `level_2` is only defined if `level_1` is 'left'. If it's not left then level_2 is not defined at all which throws the error.

Imagine if my level_1 is not "left", then when I get to the line which says `level_2.lower()` then python doesn't know what the value of level_2 is because it's never defined so it can't run the `.lower()` function

What you have to do is assign an initial value to level_2 before the if checks begin so that you dont get that error

```
level_2 = ""

level_1 = input("there is two doors infront of you type 'right' for the right door and 'left' for the left door.\n" )
level_1.lower()
if level_1 == "right" :
  print("this door is closed your level is too low to open it.\n")
if level_1 == "left" :
 level_2 = input("you found a two ladder one leads to upstairs type 'upstairs' and another leads to the basement type 'basement'.\n ")
level_2.lower()
```

Comment: aha i see what you mean but i fixed it without adding new level_2 just fixed the indentation for each if after the second choice i updated the new code to see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `level_2` is only being given a value if you choose left in `level_1`. If you choose right, it prints `this door is closed your level is too low to open it.` but then `level_2` stays undefined so it raises the error. You could do the above answer, or you could add a `while` loop that runs until `level_1` is left.

```
print("Welcome to the dungeon.")
print("Your mission is to find the ursine sword.")

level_1 = ''
while level_1 != 'left':
 level_1 = input("there is two doors infront of you type 'right' for the right door and 'left' for the left door.\n")
 level_1.lower()
 if level_1 == 'right':
    print("this door is closed your level is too low to open it.\n")
 else:
     pass

level_2 = input("you found a two ladder one leads to upstairs type 'upstairs' and another leads to the basement type 'basement'.\n ")
level_2.lower()
if level_2 == "basement" :
    print("hisssssss ,  you got bitten by snake game over")
if level_2 == "upstairs" :
    level_3 =int(input("it seems like the final room thre is three swords infront of you two of them must be traps chose '1','2' or '3' "))
if level_3 == 1 :
    print("you released a powerful ghost you'r dead")
elif level_3 == 3 :
    print("you opened a portal to a cater you're dead")
elif level_3 == 2 :
    print("congratulations you found the ursine sword")
else :
    print("game over.")
```

Comment: thanks for helping yes i understood that but i still didn't reach to loop section in the course i follow right now so only i can use if statement i fixed it you can see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `level_2` only gets defined when `level_1` is "left". If `level_1` is not "left", your code will continue to throw errors.

What you can do is run `lower_2.upper()` in the second if statement. That way you only call the upper method on `lower_2` after its defined. For example,

```
if level_1 == "left" :
     level_2 = input("you found a two ladder one leads to upstairs type 'upstairs' and another leads to the basement type 'basement'.\n ")
     level_2.lower()
```